# Extract text lines as displayed in textview

Tags: android

Is it possible to get each line of a multiline text as it will appear in a textview of a fixed width, with a font, size, alignment without actually drawing the textview ?

My Text is stored in a string. I can apply different font, size, alignment for the text. When passing it to my api, I want to split it into a list of Strings just how it was displayed in the app. Is this possible ?

In the view the text is formatted using the following:

```
    TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());

    LayoutParams textLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    if (itemWidth > 0) {
        textLayoutParams.width = itemWidth;
    }

    if (itemHeight == -1) {
        textLayoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    }

    textLayoutParams.leftMargin = xPosition;
    textLayoutParams.topMargin = yPosition;
    textView.setLayoutParams(textLayoutParams);
    textView.setPaintFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    font = getFontName(font);

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(font)) {
        CalligraphyUtils.applyFontToTextView(getContext(), textView, CalligraphyConfig.get(), "fonts/" + font);
    }

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(color))
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color));

    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (int)size );

    if (alignment.equalsIgnoreCase("center")) {
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    } else if (alignment.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.START);
    } else if (alignment.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.END);
    } else if (alignment.equalsIgnoreCase("left_center")) {
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER);
    }

    addView(textView);
```

For multi line strings, it will display on different lines. In a background process, I want to know which substring was displayed on 1st line, which substring was displayed on second line and so on. Is this even possible ?

Comment: what did you use to format, align,... the text? html?

Comment: add your code whatever you try